# What is the color code for the top bar of Zen Mode of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I am almost crazy not able to find the proper color code for the top bar (containing the breadcrumb) of **Zen Mode of VS Code**. I want to colorize it with custom setting, but I have tried a lot of "`...Background`" items without success.

Please instruct if anyone knows the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`"editorGroupHeader.noTabsBackground"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This makes sense, but not effective for me though, VS Code v1.72.2 on macOS 11.6.

Answer (score 0):

So far I am not successful with any variable yet. I can only style it with CustomizeUI package installed, and using `customizeUI.stylesheet` setting to write styles for the `.tabs-and-actions-container` element.

Comment: Good to see you've had some partial progress, good luck!